# GLFW engine and the main thread issue IntelliJ

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, lwjgl

I am using a Mac OS x. My IDE is Intellij. For some reason I get an error when trying to run this code. The code is an lwjgl game engine.

```
import org.lwjgl.glfw.*;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.*;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.Callbacks.*;
import org.lwjgl.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.applet.Applet;

public class Main implements Runnable{

private int width = 1280;
private int height =720;
private String title = "Flappy";

private boolean running = false;
private Thread thread;
private long window;

public void start(){
    running = true;

    thread = new Thread(this, "Display");
    //this will call the run method that we created below by using our implemented Runnable
    thread.start();
}

public void run(){
    init();
    running = true;
      while(running){
        update();
        render();
        if(glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
            running = false;
        }
    }
}

//init initializes all of our stuff
private void init(){

    if(!glfwInit()){
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW YOOO");
    }

    // Configure our window
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE); // the window will stay hidden after creation
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE); // the window will be resizable

    window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title, NULL, NULL);

    if(window == NULL){
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create the GLFW window");
    }


    GLFWVidMode vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
    glfwSetWindowPos(window, (vidmode.width() - width) / 2, (vidmode.height() - height) / 2);
    // Make the OpenGL context current
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    // Enable v-sync
    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    // Make the window visible
    glfwShowWindow(window);

}



public void update(){
    glfwPollEvents();
}

public void render(){
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}


public static void main(String[] args){
    new Main().start();
}
}
```

Reading some posts I tried adding -XstartOnFirstThread to Edit Configure and program argument but that didn't help. My error if below. If anyone could help, thanks... Again using a Mac with Intellij. The error is added below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GLFW windows may only be created on the main thread and that thread must be the first thread in the process. Please run the JVM with -XstartOnFirstThread. For offscreen rendering, make sure another window toolkit (e.g. AWT or JavaFX) is initialized before GLFW.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GLFW Window Crashing Even With "-XstartOnFirstThread" In VM Arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333723/glfw-window-crashing-even-with-xstartonfirstthread-in-vm-arguments)

Comment: How can I be more specific? This issue was solved in another post, and the answer I provided there is pretty self explanatory.

Comment: I changed it to run it all on the main thread. I have it exactly like they show it here: https://www.lwjgl.org/guide still the same error

Comment: @NikBabinchuk Did you notice **"WARNING: The code below requires the latest nightly build to compile and run."** at that link? I dont think you are using the lastest nightly build.

Comment: So whats the f'n solution? I've changed it back to the code above, got rid of the thread I've created and am running everything on the main thread. Still get the same error.....

Comment: Can someone please post a way they would write that code correctly?

Comment: @NikBabinchuk how about a full tutorial? [Lightweight Java Game Library 3 Tutorial](https://github.com/SilverTiger/lwjgl3-tutorial/wiki) And a book? [lwjglbook](https://github.com/lwjglgamedev/lwjglbook)

Comment: As long as you still have the -XstartOnFirstThread flag, the code on lwjgl.org/guide should work just fine. Also, relooking at your post, it isn't supposed to be a Program argument, but a VM Argument (Or whatever IntelliJ calls it).

Comment: Finally fixed it. The -XstartOnFirstThread needed to be in the VM Options section in Intellij and it works with the lwjgl.org/guide code....

Answer (score 16):

I met the same error with Intellij 2017.1.3; mac os 10.12.4; lwjgl-release-3.1

It solved by click Menu - Run -> Edit Configurations... and then add the parameter -XstartOnFirstThread to the text box beside VM options:

Screen print:
[image]

Answer (score 11):

For those with missing VM options, this field is hidden, here:

Run -> Edit Configurations... -> Modify options dropdown -> Add VM options -> -XstartOnFirstThread

[image: screen print]

Comment:  this answer is more relevant to the latest version of Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

The exception you got is very clear about the issue, your `init()` method which calls `glfwCreateWindow()` to create `GLFW Window` should be called from a `main thread`. So make your `init()` method public and remove the `init();` call inside the `run()` method. Instead change your main method to this;

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   Main main = new Main();
   main.init();
   main.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the build.gradle file built the The Initializer, you can add this section, to specify the Java command line option:

```
application {
    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ['-XstartOnFirstThread']
}
```